# I want only the authenticated users picture to show

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I am learning Laravel.
I have a picture gallery tha shows all pictures paginated but I want to only show on another page the users photos
So this is the controller for the only users photos to show

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function show(Photos $photos)
    {           
        $user = auth()->user();
        $images = Photos::all();
        if($images->user->user_id==auth()->id())
        {
            return view('profile',['images'=>$images,
                'user'=>$user]);
        }
    }

     //This is my photos table

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedinteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('photos');
    } 

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedinteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
'
```

And this is the route:

```
//users gallery
Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@show')->name('profile');
```

This is my photos model:

```
 // protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','title','image'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

And this is my user model:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'username','firstname','lastname','phone', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photos::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function favorite()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Favorites::class);
   }
```

The problem is that is still shows all the photos not only the user's one. Please tell me what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `show` method in your controller should be

```
public function show()
{           
    return view('profile',['images' => Photo::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate(10),'user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn work  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method links does not exist. (View: /home/www/gallery/resources/views/profile.blade.php)